# Puppet: stage main not found?

Tags: puppet, rvm

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/blt04/puppet-rvm) RVM puppet module, but puppet is complaining that it can't find Stage[main]:

```
Could not find stage main specified by Class[Rvm] at /etc/puppet/modules/rvm/manifests/system.pp:3
```

Has anyone encountered this in the past?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of puppet are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but run stages were added in Puppet 2.6.0.  Are you on a version older than that?